# Drawbacks to only using TLS 1.2 ciphers in OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, tls, openssl, cipher-selection

I understand you would not want to do this as it would limit compatibility for older devices and platforms. However if someone were in an all TLS1.2 environment, say a very well managed internal corporate network with all up to date browsers, is there any reason to keep TLS1.0 enabled?

Comment: The only reason to maintain TLS1.0 or SSL3.0 is to be compatible with older clients. Browsers are usually the first user tool to support TLS1.2. Web applications usually are dead last. Java applications are not always well maintained or migrated to the lastest JRE version, so if you have any Java version prior to 1.7, it will fail to connect.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the only drawback is compatibility. But if that's not an issue for you then you're golden.